# VBA "Object required" error

Tags: excel, vba

I am dealing with VBA for the first time and am having trouble figuring out what is wrong with this method:

---

```
Private Sub NewProductButton_Click()

'Find the first empty row in the Products sheet

Dim inputcell As Long, lastcell As Long
inputcell = Products.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
lastcell = Products.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
'Submit form data to the sheet
Cells(inputcell, 1) = lastcell + 1
Cells(inputcell, 2) = ProdNameBox
Cells(inputcell, 3) = ProdTypeComboBox
Cells(inputcell, 4) = PrepTimeBox
Cells(inputcell, 5) = CostBox
Cells(inputcells, 6) = PriceBox
'Clear the form
Me.ProdNameBox.Value = ""
Me.ProdTypeComboBox.Value = ""
Me.PrepTimeBox.Value = ""
Me.CostBox.Value = ""
Me.PriceBox.Value = ""

End Sub
```

---

This method is supposed to enter the data into the first empty row of the sheet (from a form). The debugger highlights `inputcell = Products.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row` and throws the error. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` to the top of your module.  This will help _you_ locate the source of the error

Comment: @chrisneilsen is right. What he's trying to say is declare your variables. It is easier to debug codes with properly declared variables

Answer (score 1):

Im assuming that Products is the name of the sheet. If that is the case you need to use:

```
inputcell = Sheets("Products").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
lastcell = Sheets("Products").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)
```